# VScode C/C++ extension setup and configuration (macOS)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am new to C++ and am still trying to set up the C/C++ extension in vscode.

I followed this tutorial provided by vscode official:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_cc-configuration.

With the "lauch.json", "tasks.json", and "c_cpp_properties.json" files completed, I clicked the "play" icon, but my debugger still always show error with ";" and would open the launch.json file.

I think I am encountering the exact same problem with this post but its solution fails to solve mine: [Mac VSCode Debugger always show error about ';' and ':'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982685/mac-vscode-debugger-always-show-error-about-and).

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

for (const string& word : msg)
{
    cout << word << " ";
}

vector<string> aaa {"H", "E", "L", "L", "O"};
for (const string& word : aaa)
{
    cout << word << " ";
}


cout << endl;
}
```

This is my launch.json file:

```
    {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my tasks.json file:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

This is my c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
            ],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You must edit launch.json: `"program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out"`. You seem not followed the instructions you reference, since they do not have such config example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `program` field is not right in `launch.json`, if your CPP name is `your-program.cpp`, you could set the `program` field to `your-program`.

Because the compiling output file name is `"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"` as you set in `tasks.json`:

```json
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "your-program", // set it to right name.
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```